# Where can I download data on registered Canadian charities (form T3010) in bulk?

Tags: data-request, canada

I'm looking for a data source that will let me download, in bulk, machine-readable format, the list of all charities that file form T3010, along with information about the organization. Ideally I'd like the following info:

- Name
- CRA category code
- Revenue
- Expenses
- Any other fields on the form

You can [request these data from the CRA](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/charities-giving/charities/guidance-videos-forms/request-charities-listings.html), but this can take up to four weeks and I can't look at the data beforehand. Is there anywhere (similar to, in the US, the IRS' bulk download tools) where I can just download the full list for the most recent tax year as a machine readable file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Data Canada portal should help
https://search.open.canada.ca/en/od/?sort=score%20desc&page=1&search_text=T3010

Alternatively, you could parse the data from [List of charities search](https://apps.cra-arc.gc.ca/ebci/hacc/srch/pub/dsplyAdvncdSrch)